# Reading Form Data posed to an html page

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I am trying to use jQuery/Javascript to read Form Data that is posed to an html page. Here is the scenario

I have a page "Page1.html" which users are directed to to register for a conference. On this page I have a button wich allows them to pay. When they click this button they are taken to a payment gateway where they can pay. This payment provider then posts their response back to "Page2.html" in a Form.

Everything works fine, but I cannot seem to access the Form Data in Page2.html. I cannot event see the Form in the View Source of the page. I know the data is there as when I look at the headers using the developer tools in Chrome I can see the data. I thought $("[name=value]").val() would work but it returns undefined.

Any ideas how I go about accessing Form Data posed to an html page within that page. I do not want to use a server side script like asp.net to get to the data, although this does work, i want to use only Jquery or javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use server side to capture form data.. jQuery alone cannot do it.